# Send current PDF as read-only via Mail

Tags: javascript, adobe

I want to send a PDF via mail using a button in the PDF.  Button exists, current code looks like this:

```
var To= "a@b.com";
var CC= "";
var Subject= "Subject";
var Text="Text";

this.mailDoc({bUI: true, cTo: To, cCc: CC, cSubject: Subject, cMsg: Text});
```

So far, so good. But the PDF should be a attetchment with read-only options for all fields and the "Mail"-Button should not be there anymore. How can I achive this?

Thanks.

Comment: *"PDF should be a attetchment with read-only options"* ... You need to clarify what you mean by "read-only".

Comment: I mean write-protection: dropdowns can't be changed, text fields values are final, ...

Comment: A "drop down" via html `option` tag in `select`? Perhaps show your client-side (html portion) code to give further clarity in your question. There's little point for me (or anyone else) to guess at what you already know to be the requirement exactly, but dont have the terminology for,

Comment: I don't know. I am a beginner in this case. I am using Adobe Acrobat Pro for the first time and my new task is it to create writeable pdf forms. And then they have to be send. Sorry, I don't know how to discribe it more accurate, because I don't know the technical terms.